# Why is justify content space between not working for the icons

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So i am trying to recreate a instagram post page using html and css
But i don't understand why justify content not working
Also if there are any suggestions to do this faster or easy way pls let me know
Also pls explain why does the justify content not work properly in this case.I tried many different variations but still am not able to figure out what's wrong it would be great if anyone can help

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Instagram View Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="/img/Instagram logo.png" width="103px" height="29px" alt="" />
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search" class="search" />
      </div>
      <div class="navigation">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <img src="/icons/home.svg" height="22px" width="22px" alt="" />
          </li>
          <li>
            <img src="/icons/send.svg" height="22px" width="22px" alt="" />
          </li>
          <li>
            <img src="/icons/compass.svg" height="22px" width="22px" alt="" />
          </li>
          <li>
            <img src="/icons/user.svg" height="22px" width="22px" alt="" />
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="post">
      <div class="postimage">
        <img src="/img/Knowmad.jpg" alt="" />
      </div>

      <div class="post-details">
        <div class="accountdetails">
          <img src="/img/Knowmadlogo1.png" alt="" />
          <div class="accountname">
            <h2>knowmadin</h2>
            <p>Everywhere</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="links">
          <a href="#">Follow</a>
        </div>
        <div class="features">
          <div class="like">
            <ul>
              <li>
                <img
                  src="/icons/heart(1).svg"
                  height="40px"
                  width="40px"
                  alt=""
                />
              </li>
              <li>
                <img
                  src="/icons/comment.svg"
                  height="40px"
                  width="40px"
                  alt=""
                />
              </li>
              <li>
                <img src="/icons/send.svg" 
                height="40px" 
                width="40px" 
                alt="" />
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="bookmark">
            <img src="/icons/bookmark.svg" height="40px" width="40px" alt="" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
nav {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 10vh;
  flex-direction: row;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(var(--ce3, 239, 239, 239), 1);
}
.logo {
  display: flex;
  padding-left: 10rem;
  flex: 1;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.search {
  height: 2.8vh;
  width: 18vw;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.navigation {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}
.navigation ul {
  padding-right: 10rem;
  padding-left: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1 1 40rem;
}
.post {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;

  margin-left: 7rem;
  margin-right: 7rem;
  margin-top: 3rem;
}
.postimage img {
  width: 50vw;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}
.post-details {
  padding-left: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 10vh;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(var(--ce3, 239, 239, 239), 1);
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}
.accountdetails {
  align-items: center;

  display: flex;
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 80%;
  padding-right: 1rem;
}

.accountdetails img {
  display: flex;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  align-self: center;
}
.accountname {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.links a {
  padding-left: 1rem;
  color: blue;
}
div:empty {
  min-height: 60vh;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(var(--ce3, 239, 239, 239), 1);
}
.like {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;

  bottom: 2rem;
}
.features {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: absolute;

  bottom: 1rem;
}

.like ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  list-style: none;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.bookmark {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 1rem;
  right: 1rem;
}
```

Comment: why trying to use justify content to creat space? Either use margin or a grid with grid-gap. Do you have actually a picture of what you trying to recreate?

Comment: there are several selectors are applying justify-content, which one you are referring to? The .navigation ul?

Comment: the features ul

Comment: @tacoshy r u saying for every element individually?

Comment: no depending on what you actually trying to achieve visual wise and how you want to do it. If you implement a grid, then you need to define the grid-gap only once.

Comment: @tacoshy its a instagram post take any of the post i used the svgs for the like comment share thing and it doesn't space correctly

Comment: @tacoshy so are you saying using css grid would be better?

Comment: I have no clear picture of what you're actually trying to achieve. Thats why I asked for an example picture or drawing of the layout you want. However a Grid is a modern solution to most placement problems.

Comment: Here's the link https://www.instagram.com/p/B_MnW4IJyUZ/

Comment: Please see how to create a [MRE] with just the code that you are having problems with. This will make it easier for us to understand what you are asking and be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.features {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  
}
.like {width: 100%;}
.like ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  list-style: none;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="features">
          <div class="like">
            <ul>
              <li>
                <img
                  src="https://www.flaticon.com/svg/static/icons/svg/3520/3520171.svg"
                  height="40px"
                  width="40px"
                  alt=""
                />
              </li>
              <li>
                <img
                  src="https://www.flaticon.com/svg/static/icons/svg/3520/3520171.svg"
                  height="40px"
                  width="40px"
                  alt=""
                />
              </li>
              <li>
                <img src="https://www.flaticon.com/svg/static/icons/svg/3520/3520171.svg" 
                height="40px" 
                width="40px" 
                alt="" />
              </li>
              <li>
                <img src="https://www.flaticon.com/svg/static/icons/svg/3520/3520171.svg" 
                height="40px" 
                width="40px" 
                alt="" />
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          
          </div>
```